Error while installing ErpNext from forked repo in Frappe cloud's private bench
I am trying to install ErpNext from a forked repo into my private bench. However, I am getting an “Internal Server Error” on clicking the “Validate App” button( as seen in the screenshot attached).

On investigating the network calls in Chrome on clicking “Validate App”, I found this in the response.
{"exception":"KeyError: 'content'","exc_type":"KeyError","_exc_source":"press (app)","exc":"[\"Traceback (most recent call last):\\n File \\\"apps/frappe/frappe/app.py\\\", line 110, in application\\n response = frappe.api.handle(request)\\n File \\\"apps/frappe/frappe/api/__init__.py\\\", line 49, in handle\\n data = endpoint(**arguments)\\n File \\\"apps/frappe/frappe/api/v1.py\\\", line 36, in handle_rpc_call\\n return frappe.handler.handle()\\n File \\\"apps/frappe/frappe/handler.py\\\", line 49, in handle\\n data = execute_cmd(cmd)\\n File \\\"apps/frappe/frappe/handler.py\\\", line 85, in execute_cmd\\n return frappe.call(method, **frappe.form_dict)\\n File \\\"apps/frappe/frappe/__init__.py\\\", line 1795, in call\\n return fn(*args, **newargs)\\n File \\\"apps/frappe/frappe/utils/typing_validations.py\\\", line 31, in wrapper\\n return func(*args, **kwargs)\\n File \\\"apps/press/press/api/github.py\\\", line 218, in app\\n app_name, title = _get_app_name_and_title_from_hooks(\\n File \\\"apps/press/press/api/github.py\\\", line 283, in _get_app_name_and_title_from_hooks\\n content = b64decode(hooks[\\\"content\\\"]).decode()\\nKeyError: 'content'\\n\"]"}
Please help me understand what am I doing wrong.
